# Inno Setup - How to automatically allow Java through firewall

Tags: java, inno-setup, payara, windows-firewall, netsh

I am trying to install `Payara` through `inno setup` and when I run the `setup.bat` file, Windows firewall is blocking Java and it requires the user to click on Allow access button each time to continue with the installation.

I have added the below code in the `iss` file before executing the batch file to create a rule to allow Java through firewall, but I am still getting the prompt.

> Filename: "netsh.exe"; Parameters: "advfirewall firewall add rule
>   name=""Java 8"" dir=in action=allow
>   program=""C:\Servers\java\bin\javaw.exe"" enable=yes"; Flags:
>   RunHidden; StatusMsg: "Configuring Firewall for Java 8...";

I call the batch file using the below code.

> Filename:
>   "C:\Servers\install\setup.bat";
>   StatusMsg: "Starting Payara...";

What am I missing here?

P.S. - I am using Windows 10.

Comment: And does that command allow Java, if you run it manually on Windows command-line?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/947709/how-to-use-the-netsh-advfirewall-firewall-context-instead-of-the-netsh Your installer can call relevant commands to manipulate Windows Firewall, but keep in mind your end users might use an alternative firewall.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, even when I run manually, java is not allowed automatically. The user I am running have Admin rights too.

Comment: @LexLi, I used the mentioned link to create a firewall rule in the first place. The rule is created perfectly, but I am still getting this allow java prompt. I need to have a silent installation and this prompt is not helping.

Comment: I just changed the allow program from `javaw.exe` to `java.exe` and now the access is allowed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The firewall rule needs to be changed to allow `java.exe` instead of `javaw.exe` and it will be allowed automatically without a prompt. The updated rule is mentioned below.

```
Filename: "netsh.exe"; Parameters: "advfirewall firewall add rule name=""Java 8"" dir=in action=allow program=""C:\Servers\java\bin\java.exe"" enable=yes";
```